# Button only works on click, not on enter/return

Tags: javascript, button, passwords

I have a simple password protection set up on my website to keep out random visitors and give clients a sense of security.

I understand that the password can be easily pulled from the source code, but that isn't a problem.

When the password is entered, it only works if the button is clicked. When enter is hit (which most people default to), it just reloads the page with "?pass=password" at the end of the location. It would be ideal if the button could be clicked and/or enter could be pressed.

**In head...**

```
</script>
<!--- PASSWORD PROTECTION SCRIPT --->    
function TheLogin() {    
   var password = 'accessportfolio';    
   if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
      window.location.href="protected.html#portfolio";
   } else {
      location.href="incorrect.html";
   }
}    
<!--- End hiding --->
</script>
```

**In Body...**

```
<form name="login" style="margin: 0px">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pass" size="17"
       onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;" 
       style="width: 250px; margin: 5px;"><br>
<input type="button" value="CLICK TO ACCESS" 
       style="width : 150px; margin: 10px"
       onClick="TheLogin(this.form)">
</form>
```

Comment: use `onSubmit` not `onClick` which will by definition only work on click.

Answer (score 0):

The button should be a submit button and you should be using onsubmit of the form and not onclick of a button.

```js
function TheLogin() {
  var password = 'accessportfolio';
  if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
    window.location.href = "protected.html#portfolio";
  } else {
    location.href = "incorrect.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="login" style="margin: 0px" onsubmit="TheLogin(); return false;">
  <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pass" size="17" style="width: 250px; margin: 5px;">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="CLICK TO ACCESS" style="width : 150px; margin: 10px">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this and it is not working properly (not sure if I am doing it correctly). If you have time to take a look I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I just edited my html file and it is still not working. Since my website is a single page, do you think the code is interfering with something else? Once I type in the password "accessportfolio" and hit enter, it just reloads and displays "http://wesrobertsdesign.com/?pass=accessportfolio" in the address bar. I really appreciate your time with this.

Comment: `onsubmit="TheLogin(); return false;"`